# Eigenfunction and partial derivative (linearity)

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

After noting that $x \to e^{ixp}$ is an eigenvector (with eigenvalue $p$) of the endomorphism $\hat p:u \to  \frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, my teacher goes one step beyond and states that $x \to \int dp\Phi(p)e^{ixp}$ is also an eigenvector (with eigenvalue $p$) of the same endomorphism $\hat p$ using the **linearity** argument.

I've understood the linearity argument. However, I don't understand how, "formally", we can conclude this result since
$$\hat p (x \to \int dp\Phi(p)e^{ixp}) = x \to\frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\int dp\Phi(p)e^{ixp}\\ =x\to\frac{1}{i}\int dp\Phi(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{ixp}=x\to\int dp\Phi(p)pe^{ixp}$$ and this last term is *from my point of view* (I may be wrong...!) different from $p(x\to\int dp\Phi(p)e^{ixp})$

I already asked in physics.SE (since it departs from a Quantum Mechanics problem), I am confused about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have badly misunderstood your teacher, or he has misled you, badly.

Indeed, the momentum operator is linear,
$$
\hat p \equiv \int\!\! dx ~|x\rangle \frac{\partial_x}{i}    \langle x| , \implies \\ 
\langle x|\hat p|u\rangle \equiv \hat p _x ~u(x)=  \frac{\partial_x u}{i},
$$
so that $u(x)= e^{ixp}$ is an eigenvector  of it, with eigenvalue $p$.

The statement that $ u(x)= \int dp\Phi(p)e^{ixp}$ is also an eigenvector of it is flat wrong. Indeed, by linearity,
$$\hat p_x  ~ \int\!\! dp~\Phi(p)e^{ixp} =  \frac{\partial_x}{i} \int\!\! dp~\Phi(p)e^{ixp} \\
  = \int dp~\Phi(p)~p~e^{ixp},$$ and  and you are right you may not take the dummy variable out of the integral, so that integral is not an eigenvector of the momentum operator in the *x*-representation.

You might discuss with your instructor what he had in mind, but, almost certainly, not the false statement you are positing. The statement is only true for $\Phi(p)=\delta (p-p_0)$, in which case the eigenvalue would be $p_0$, and "almost" correct with the δ-function supplanted by a very sharply peaked function.

---

*Addendum post OP's comment*

Indeed, if *u(x)* corresponds to a sharply peaked $$\Phi (p-p_0)=\frac{e^{-(p-p_0)^2/\epsilon }}{\sqrt{\pi \epsilon}} \\
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \Phi(p)=\delta (p-p_0), $$
you can see from your integral that
$$
\hat p_x u(x)= p_0 u(x) + \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\pi}}e^{ixp_0}\int \!\!dy ~y e^{-y^2} e^{ixy\sqrt{\epsilon}} 
$$
so the eigenvalue equation is corrected by an insignificant term of $O(\sqrt \epsilon)$.

Comment: *"almost" correct with the δ-function supplanted by a very sharply peaked function.*  The teacher makes exactly this assumption: the $\Phi$ function peaks sharply around a certain value..

Comment: This is essential information and should not be missing. Take a Gaussian with with ε, and compute. Show your work. Do you want me to do that for you?

Comment: If you can, yes please! I will try to take a Gaussian instead of $\Phi$ then show what I have

Comment: I just did.....